# How to reorder taskkill result as table

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to know how to re-organize the result of a command into a table with my own answers within a batch file for windows xp pro. For instance if I run the command:

```
taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe
```

And the result is:

> SUCCESS: The process "iexplore.exe" with PID 1553 has been terminated.

I want my table to do this

```
___________________________________________________________________________
|             Process               |              Result                 |
|___________________________________|_____________________________________|
|                                   |                                     |
|         iexplore.exe              |      Successfully terminated        |
|                                   |                                     |
___________________________________________________________________________
```

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way of doing this!  But it's going to take some effort in a batch file.  You'll likely find something like Powershell more suited to the task.  Any specific questions you have along the way, please ask them and we'll be happy to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET returntext=SUCCESS: The process "iexplore.exe" with PID 1553 has been terminated.

::
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('echo %returntext%') DO (
CALL :report %%i
)
GOTO :eof

:report
IF %1==SUCCESS: SET process=%~4&SET result=Successfully terminated
:: other translations if required...
(SET text=)&CALL :centre 75 _
SET uscore75=%text%

ECHO %uscore75%

CALL :writec1c2 Process Result
CALL :writec1c2 _ _ _
CALL :writec1c2
CALL :writec1c2 "%process%" "%result%"
CALL :writec1c2
ECHO %uscore75%

GOTO :eof

:writec1c2
SET text=%~1&CALL :centre 36 %3
(SET col1=%text%)
SET text=%~2&CALL :centre 36 %3
(SET col2=%text%)
ECHO ^|%col1%^|%col2%^|
GOTO :eof

:centre
SET fill=%2
IF NOT DEFINED fill (SET fill= )
:centrelp
(SET text=%fill%%text%%fill%)
CALL SET done=%%text:~%1%%
IF NOT DEFINED done GOTO centrelp
CALL SET text=%text:~1%
CALL SET done=%%text:~%1%%
IF DEFINED done SET text=%text:~0,-1%
GOTO :eof
```

I've set your return message into a variable which gets `ECHO`ed as the source 'file' for the `FOR /F`. In your real case, you'd use the taskkill command between the quotes.

When the procedure `:report` is called, the entire line is delivered as parameters.

The first parameter is SUCCESS: and the fourth "iexplore.exe"

Since you give no clue as to how else you may wish to use it, I've simply set `PROCESS` to the 4th parameter, stripping the quotes and `RESULT` to the text you used.

Next step is a routine which centres the string in `TEXT` in a field width given as its first parameter and an optional fill character as its second. This returns `TEXT` with the length specified and the original contents centred between the fill character specified.

hence `(SET text=)&CALL :centre 75 _` returns `TEXT` as 75 underscores. This is stored in `uscore75`

The routine `:writec1c2` writes out the two columns with a leading and trailing pipe plus a pipe between the two columns. The two text items for the columns are supplied as the first 2 parameters and the fill character as the third. All `:writec1c2` needs to do is to centre the two text items in a field of 36 spaces and write out the resultant line.

Calling `:writec1c2` with three underscores means that the "column text" is an underscore in each case, and they're filled to length 36 with underscores...

---

Here's a slightly reformatted version.

It starts an `iexplore` instance then

- Waits 8 sec for iexplore.exe to start up
- Starts the report with the header
- Terminates `iexplore` using `taskkill` and reports results
- Attempts to terminate `iexplore` again and reports the failure
- Ends the report with a footer.

I've added a lot more documentation, too.

In the `:report` routine, I've included and jumped-over a bit of code which would display the parameters delivered from `TASKKILL`. Note the difference between `%n` and %~n` - the first retains the quotes and the second removes them.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
::
:: Use local routine to make a line of 75 underscores and store it
::
(SET text=)&CALL :centre 75 _
SET uscore75=%text%

::
:: Start iexplore.exe
::
START "Window title here" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.google.com
::
:: Wait 8 secs for it to start
::

timeout /t 8 >nul

:: Produce the header lines...
ECHO %uscore75%
CALL :writec1c2 Process Result
CALL :writec1c2 _ _ _
CALL :writec1c2

::
:: Now kill iexplore.exe... there will be 2 instances (greedy!)
::
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe 2^>^&1') DO (
CALL :report %%i
)

::
:: Now try again...but she's not there...(Zombies, 1964)
::

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe 2^>^&1') DO (
CALL :report %%i
)

::
:: and the report footer
::
CALL :writec1c2
ECHO %uscore75%

GOTO :eof

:report
::
:: comment-out the following GOTO to show the parameters to the routine
::
GOTO endparms
::
:: By way of explanation, this is what is delivered to the routine...
::
ECHO :report parameters=%*
SET parmno=0
:ploop
SET /a parmno=parmno + 1
IF %parmno% gtr 9 GOTO endparms
CALL SET parmvald=%%~%parmno%%
CALL SET parmval=%%%parmno%%
IF DEFINED parmval (
  ECHO parameter %parmno% (%%%parmno%^) to :report = [%parmval%] (%%~%parmno%^) = [%parmvald%]
  GOTO ploop)

:endparms

IF %1==SUCCESS: SET process=%~4&SET result=Successfully terminated
IF %1==ERROR: SET process=%~4&SET result=NOT found
:: other translations if required...

CALL :writec1c2 "%process%" "%result%"

GOTO :eof

::
:: strip the quotes from the first two parameters,
:: centre each in a string 36 characters wide.
:: The fill character is given by the third parameter.
:: If no third parameter is supplied, :centre will assume space
::
:: then write PIPE column1 PIPE column2 PIPE
:: The pipe must be escaped by a caret as pipe is a special character
::
:writec1c2
SET text=%~1&CALL :centre 36 %3
(SET col1=%text%)
SET text=%~2&CALL :centre 36 %3
(SET col2=%text%)
ECHO ^|%col1%^|%col2%^|
GOTO :eof

::
:: centre the string in %text%
:: to width %1 using character %2
:: If %2 is not given, use SPACE
::
:centre
:: Set FILL to %2
SET fill=%2
:: If it wasn't provided, set space
IF NOT DEFINED fill (SET fill= )

:centrelp
:: add the fill character to each end of %text%
(SET text=%fill%%text%%fill%)
:: 
:: Use parsing rule to set DONE to the %1th charater of %text%
:: The parser translates this as
:: CALL (SET done=%text:~[the number supplied in %1]%)
::
CALL SET done=%%text:~%1%%
:: If there was no nth character, not long enough yet, 
:: so repeat...
IF NOT DEFINED done GOTO centrelp
:: Now the string is LONGER than required length.
:: Remove the first character, which will be a FILL
:: Then repeat the same parsing trick again to trim off any excess.
CALL SET text=%text:~1%
CALL SET done=%%text:~%1%%
IF DEFINED done SET text=%text:~0,-1%
GOTO :eof
```

Note that rather than simply reporting successes and failres, `TASKKILL` sends success reports to standard output (`STDOUT`) and failure reports to standard error (`STDERR`.) These are combined by the code by `2>&1` which directs `STDERR` (2) to `STDOUT` (1) **BUT** since this is within the command executed by `FOR`, each of the special characters `>` and `&` need to be escaped by a caret `^`

Comment: ok so ive tried tweaking the batch and redoing and everything that I can think of but your explanation was very confusing and I cannot get this to work if you would. please e-mail me at mr.batchxp@gmail.com @PeterWright

Comment: Not quite how it works - the entire idea is that others may see the solution or participate in its development. I've added a revised version that may help - just add some comments (or edit your question) to clarify your changes, what errors you're getting, how it needs to be modified or whatever.